# Format valid JSON for associate object in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    a.Id, a.Title,
    (SELECT m.Id, m.Name, m.MobileNo
     FROM [msm].[MsmMember] AS m
     WHERE m.Id = a.MemberId 
       AND m.OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) AS Member
FROM 
    msm.MsmArticleSubmission a 
WHERE
    a.OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
    AND a.Id = @Id
FOR JSON PATH
```

This is the resulting output:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "A4C6B579-5D0C-4807-9537-53C6B1E8E6BA",
    "Title": "Test Data",
    "Member": "{\"Id\":\"79F87A71-332A-43CB-A944-E8C50C00CFF7\",\"Name\":\"Asma Husain Noora\",\"MobileNo\":\"00000000\"}"
  }
]
```

Here Member is not a valid JSON Format, so, when I try to deserialize from C#, the `Member` object throws an exception, because of the invalid JSON format. I couldn't figure out any solution. It works if I make "Member" an Array, but I need a single associate object only.

Tech stack: ASP.NET Core 8.0, SQL Server 2019

Comment: Is there a _good_ reason you're returning JSON from an RDBMS instead of working with relational data directly?

Comment: @Dai yeah, I need to get some associate objects (Single and Collection both) with the main object, because this object is for an HTML View Page, and lots of tables are associated with this Object, so without Json, I cant solve this in a single query without repetition data.
I Can do this from the C# side using EF and LINQ, but using SP or VIEW is more appropriate to do this type of work.

Comment: You can do that using a batched query: two separate `SELECT` statements with a couple of `DECLARE`'d variables wrapped in a `TRANSACTION` for consistency - you don't need JSON for this. Then read it using a `SqlDataReader` (which supports multiple resultsets via `await rdr.NextResultAsync()`).

Comment: okay great, can you please suggest to me any sample links?

Comment: I'm not aware of any articles that discuss it because it's kinda a fundamental topic...

Comment: That means you want to say, I write multiple queries and get by One Batch operation, after retrieving data, I need to bind specific object and properties data, right?

Comment: @Dai I must say I cannot replicate this issue https://dbfiddle.uk/HLRGdlaw as far as I know this double-escaping only happens when the JSON string is used in another expression, such as `isnull` or `case`. Otherwise it can detect that it's valid JSON

Comment: @Charlieface I haven't tried to reproduce the JSON encoding issue at all

Comment: @Charlieface Curiously, the double-encoding also happens if you use `FOR XML AUTO` instead of `FOR JSON` - except it's double-XML-encoding. _Weird_. I'm tempted to think it's to do with SSMS rather than SQL Server tho

Comment: @Dai That would be expected: XML is not valid JSON. I see the normal XML escaping then JSON escaping on top, not double XML escaping https://dbfiddle.uk/iW-U_ITG But I don't see this happening when I use `FOR JSON` directly in a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```sql
SELECT 
    a.Id, a.Title,
    JSON_QUERY((SELECT m.Id, m.Name, m.MobileNo
     FROM [msm].[MsmMember] AS m
     WHERE m.Id = a.MemberId 
       AND m.OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)) AS Member
FROM 
    msm.MsmArticleSubmission a 
WHERE
    a.OrganizationId = @OrganizationId
    AND a.Id = @Id
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much, I spent more than 6 hours, and even chatGPT never suggested this function for a single time.
Now everything is working as expected. Jajakallah brother, love you from Bangladesh.